# How to update data to Live sever with N duration time period

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a Web application (MySQL and PHP), and I am handling the data from local database. Now I need to take a backup. So I desired to use two databases. One for local database (for entering data). Another one to backup.

Now the problem is to update the live server. Because I don't want to upload full database each and every time. I just need (e.g. for 1 hours only) within the particular time what type of operations are done (`CRUD` operations) only to be sent to my second server. I tried lots but nothing works.

**Edit 1:** I did a full database backup and uploaded to my second sever, but I need particular data because full database means large amount of data so it's a risky task and I don't what that.

Comment: "Replication" keeps two servers (a Master and a Slave) in sync.  Is that what you want?

Comment: but my one of senior done that using C# and mysql trigger concepts  actually its working good. @RickJames. And there is `NO Replication`